# How to use json2html with random keys

Tags: javascript, json, json2html

So, I clearly understand how to transform JSON to HTML if I know what type of data i will get in json.

But how can I use json2html if I don't know what kind of keys I will get from server?

Here code, that works correctly with static keys:

```js
var data = {'json': [{
    'order': 'By',
        'name': 'Stack',
        'randomkey': '3',
        'randomkey_n': '0',
        'score': '121',
        'id': '540'
}]};

var transform = {
    tag: 'tr',
    children: [{
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${order}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${name}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${randomkey}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${randomkey_n}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${score}"
    }]
};

$('#placar > tbody ').json2html(data.json, transform);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://json2html.com/js/json2html.js"></script>
<script src="http://json2html.com/js/jquery.json2html.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p>
        <table id="placar" class="table table-condensed  table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

I understand, that I should use inline function in `transform`, but I can't understand how to return value of "random" keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the properties with `Object.keys`, exclude the `id` property (as you seem not to render it) with `.filter()` and finally `.map()` those to the object structure you need for the `children` property:

```js
var data = {'json': [{
    'order': 'By',
        'name': 'Stack',
        'randomkey': '3',
        'randomkey_n': '0',
        'score': '121',
        'id': '540'
}]};

var transform = {
    tag: 'tr',
    children: Object.keys(data.json[0]) // get keys
        .filter(key => key !== 'id') // exclude id
        .map(key => ({ // convert to object for transformation
            "tag": "td",
            "html": "${" + key + "}"
        }))
};

$('#placar > tbody ').json2html(data.json, transform);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://json2html.com/js/json2html.js"></script>
<script src="http://json2html.com/js/jquery.json2html.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p>
        <table id="placar" class="table table-condensed  table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

#### Filtering out more than one key

In case you have other properties that should be excluded like *id*, then you could do this:

```
.filter(key => !['id', 'otherfield', 'comment'].includes(key))
```

Or, if you have many such properties, improve efficiency by first defining a set once:

```
const excludes = new Set(['id', 'otherfield', 'comment', /* many others...*/]);
```

...and then the filtering becomes:

```
.filter(key => !excludes.has(key))
```

Comment: I need one more answer from you :) i understood that - filter(key => ...) = filter(function(key){return key!== 'id'}, but i didn't understand how can i exclude more than 1 key with this arrow function example. I've just started learning js :)

Comment: I added some ideas to my answer.

Comment: oh! yeah, array and includes = boolean retrun :) nice, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer tincot .. just to add another way of doing this that might be a little easier to understand.  You could transform the json object into an array with the property name and value then use a static transform

```
var data = {'json': [{
    'order': 'By',
        'name': 'Stack',
        'randomkey': '3',
        'randomkey_n': '0',
        'score': '121',
        'id': '540'
}]};

var transform = {"<>": "tr","html":[
            {"<>":"td","html":"${val}"}
        ]};

var _data = [];

for(var i=0; i < data.json.length; i++){

  var out = [];

  for(var prop in data.json[i]) 
    if(prop !== "id") out[i] = {"name":prop,"val":data.json[i][prop]};

  _data.push(out);
}

$('#placar > tbody ').json2html(_data, transform);
```